# Previous and Next buttons are not working in web page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created image slide show. The code is below

**HTML**

```
<div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/bf/5f/95/bf5f9539ea9fa3eee60e961b7e50c8e1.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">

  <img src="http://www.holifestival.org/images/holi-image-4-big.jpg" style="width:100%">

</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">

  <img src="https://searchengineland.com/figz/wp-content/seloads/2016/03/google-photos-images-camera-ss-1920-800x450.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

</div>
<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {box-sizing: border-box}
body {font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; margin:0}
.mySlides {display: none}
img {vertical-align: middle;}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev, .next,.text {font-size: 11px}
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
       slides[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
    setTimeout(showSlides, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds

}
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}
```

It workes as per my need but when it comes to previous button and next buttons clicked it is not moving to as per previous slide or next slide.

**Live Demo:**https://codepen.io/RamBM/pen/ppdRGo

Could any one please let me know or rectify me where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Are you gonna do it both manually and automatically?

Comment: yeah I need in both. when I do manually it is not working

Comment: Did you check your console? Seems like you renamed things (plusDivs/plusSlides, showDivs/showSlides) but not everywhere. Also slideIndex is declared twice.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue here is that you started renaming things but did not rename them all (plusDivs/plusSlides, showDivs/showSlides).

Also, slideIndex is declared twice, you should remove the second one.

You might want to clear your timeout when manually navigating, too.
Add a `var timeout` at the beginning, change your setTimeout to `timeout = setTimeout`, and then update `plusSlides`:

```
function plusSlides(n) {
  if (timeout) {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = null;
  }
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}
```

Edit: example corrected codepen https://codepen.io/kLabz/pen/BJmWab?editors=1010

Comment: I changed, still same problem

Comment: My question is the slides has move automatically and also when the user clicks on previous button it has to be move to back slide and also when the user click next slide it has to be move to next slide

Comment: There is also something weird with your handling of slideIndex (only looping when going right, not left). I added a codepen: https://codepen.io/kLabz/pen/BJmWab